# How to escape a hash (#) char in python?

Tags: python, odbc, escaping, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to query an AS400 (unfortunately), and some column names have hashes in them! Here is a small example:

```
self.cursor.execute('select LPPLNM, LPPDR# from BSYDTAD.LADWJLFU')

for row in self.cursor:
    p = Patient()
    p.last = row.LPPLNM
        p.pcp = row.LPPDR#
```

I get errors like this obviously:

```
 AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'LPPDR'
```

Is there some way to escape this? Seems doubtful that a hash is even allowed in a var name. I just picked up python today, so forgive me if the answer is common knowledge.

Thanks, Pete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `getattr` function

```
p.pcp = getattr(row, "LPPDR#")
```

This is, in general, the way that you deal with attributes which aren't legal Python identifiers.  For example, you can say

```
setattr(p, "&)(@#$@!!~%&", "Hello World!")
print getattr(p, "&)(@#$@!!~%&")  # prints "Hello World!"
```

Also, as JG suggests, you can give your columns an alias, such as by saying

```
SELECT LPPDR# AS LPPDR ...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try to give the column an alias, i.e.:

```
 self.cursor.execute('select LPPLNM, LPPDR# as LPPDR from BSYDTAD.LADWJLFU')
```

Answer (score 2):

`self.cursor.execute` returns a tuple, so this would also work:

```
for row in self.cursor:
        p = Patient()
        p.last = row[0]
        p.pcp = row[1]
```

But I prefer the other answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered, but this is just another alternative (based on Adam Bernier's answer + tuple unpacking) which I think is the cleanest:

```
for row in self.cursor:
    p = Patient()
    p.last, p.pcp = row
```